# How to Change Django Database schema in a View?

Tags: python, django, database, django-models, django-rest-framework

How can I change the database schema from a Django view?

I want the user to select a database field type.

Comment: Why should a user be able to change the database structure?

Answer (score 1):

First, `settings.py` should look something like this:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'NAME': 'schema_name',
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
        'USER': 'postgres',
        'PASSWORD': 'password'
    },
    'foo': {
        'NAME': 'schema_name',
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'USER': 'root',
        'PASSWORD': 'password'
    },
...
}
```

Now, in your code, you can manually decide which schema/database to use with the [`.using`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/db/multi-db/#manually-selecting-a-database-for-a-queryset) method:

```
SomeModel.objects.using('foo').all() #this uses "foo"
SomeModel.objects.all() #this uses "default"
```

For more complex logic, you can create a [database router](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/db/multi-db/#database-routers) do decide which schema to use in a given scenario.

### Update

You can execute [raw queries](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/db/sql/#executing-custom-sql-directly) by importing `connection`.

Here is an example create statement:

```
 from django.db import connection
 with connection.cursor() as cursor:
     sql = '''
     CREATE TABLE foo (
     col1 INT,
     col2 VARCHAR(45)
     )'''
     cursor.execute(sql)
```

You should be extremely careful when creating tables using user input.  Doing so in an unsafe way can lead to [SQL injection](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_injection.asp) and potentially other vulnerabilities like [stored xss](https://portswigger.net/web-security/cross-site-scripting/stored).

Comment: sorry , you donot understand my question, I want the user to choose the databse field type. the user selects char or int

Comment: @MahmoudAboElsoud So you want the user to *create* a table?  I still don't understand.

Comment: something like that, the user will select one of two types CharField or  IntegerField, then the code will create the table containing a field with the type the user selected

Comment: @MahmoudAboElsoud I added an update.  Is that what you are looking for?

Comment: Yes, this is very awsome, thank you. but how can I make it for all databases systems like mysql, ms sql, oracle, postgresql, ...

Comment: I mean the website checks the database used and run the sql code for it. if mysql used , run the mysql code, if oracle used , run the oracle code, ..